# Update the next element className using useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I place a .map() inside a table to render the content (tr element) from an API. On each iteration of the loop it creates an option menu (view, edit, delete). To open that menu I use useState to update the className of the target menu. The issue happens when I click a single menu button, all of the menus are changing the classname.
Is there a way that when you click an action menu, only the next sibling element will change the classname?

[normal state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6TX9.jpg)

[clicked state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tmtQ.jpg)

```
 const [toggleOption, setToggleOption] = React.useState(false);

 const handleToggleOption = () => {
   setToggleOption(!toggleOption);
 };

<tbody>
         {list.data.map((item) => {
           if (item.metadata.class === "non-resident") {
             return (
               <tr key={item.id}>
                 <td>{item.name}</td>
                 <td>{item.metadata.birthday}</td>
                 <td>{item.metadata.class}</td>
                 <td>1-20-2021</td>
                 <td className="table__option">
               {/*this is the button menu*/}
                   <button
                     className="table__option__btn"
                     onClick={handleToggleOption}
                   >
                     <span></span>
                     <span></span>
                     <span></span>
                   </button>
                {// this is the menu}
                   <ul
                     className={
                       toggleOption
                         ? "table__option__list active"
                         : "table__option__list"
                     }
                   >
                     <li>
                       <button>View</button>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                       <button>Edit</button>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                       <button>Delete</button>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </td>
               </tr>
             );
           }
           return null;
         })}
       </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new component for  elements otherwise you are using the same state for every tr element.

Your new component can be like this:

```js
const NewComponent = ({item}) => {

  const [toggleOption, setToggleOption] = React.useState(false);

  const handleToggleOption = () => {
    setToggleOption(!toggleOption);
  };

  return (
    <tr key={item.id}>
                 <td>{item.name}</td>
                 <td>{item.metadata.birthday}</td>
                 <td>{item.metadata.class}</td>
                 <td>1-20-2021</td>
                 <td className="table__option">
               {/*this is the button menu*/}
                   <button
                     className="table__option__btn"
                     onClick={handleToggleOption}
                   >
                     <span></span>
                     <span></span>
                     <span></span>
                   </button>
                {// this is the menu}
                   <ul
                     className={
                       toggleOption
                         ? "table__option__list active"
                         : "table__option__list"
                     }
                   >
                     <li>
                       <button>View</button>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                       <button>Edit</button>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                       <button>Delete</button>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                 </td>
               </tr>

  )

}
```

And then in your parent component you can replace tr tag with the new component like this:

```js
list.data.map((item) => {
           if (item.metadata.class === "non-resident") { 
            <NewComponent item={item} /> 
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it in React way, You'd better to stay with useState method but instead of boolean, Pass the id or index of that row to the state.

```
const [toggleOption, setToggleOption] = React.useState(-1);

const handleToggleOption = (index) => {
  setToggleOption(index);
};
```

And inside your map check the id/index

```
 <ul
     className={
     toggleOption===index
                     ? "table__option__list active"
                     : "table__option__list"
                 }
               >
```